# Space in caption type name (algorithm)

Tags: algorithms, naming

To include code in my document I have following in my preamble:

```
 \usepackage[Code]{algorithm}
 \usepackage{listings}
```

and following in the document body to display the actual code:

```
begin{algorithm}
\caption{Description}
\label{alg:num}
\lstset{language=custom}
\begin{lstlisting}
 my code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{algorithm}
```

This works fine until there are no spaces in the name of the caption type, i.e. `\usepackage[Code]{algorithm}` works fine but  `\usepackage[Code Snippet]{algorithm}`does not. I also tried adding the `~` symbol, but it failed too. How to add spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\ALG@name`

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \makeatletter
 \edef\ALG@name{Code snippets}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
   \begin{algorithm}
\caption{Description}
\label{alg:num}
%\lstset{language=custom}
\begin{lstlisting}
 my code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method is explained in section 4.4 (Customization) of the package manual (pages 15–16):

```
\floatname{algorithm}{Code snippet}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings}
\floatname{algorithm}{Code snippet}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Description}
\label{alg:num}
%\lstset{language=custom}
\begin{lstlisting}
my code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The method of specifying a package option doesn't work, because LaTeX removes all spaces in options, unless the package uses some key-value interface.